# ads_commandによるOPENコマンドの実行に失敗します

Tags: c++, ijcad, arx

現在、IJCAD2013からIJCAD2018へのマイグレーションを行っております。

```
ads_command(RTSTR,_T(".OPEN"),RTSTR,filePath,RTNONE);
```

上記の処理を実行すると、「コマンドが認識されません」と表示され図面のオープンに失敗します。
IJCAD2013の時には問題なく動作していて、今回もコード自体は特に変更ない状態です。
同じ位置で「ZOOM」を実行した場合は認識されました。

また、マイグレーション前後の環境は下記の通りです。
[前]
Windows7(32bit)
IJCAD2013(32bit)

[後]
Windows10(64bit)
IJCAD2018(32bit)

何か回避策があればご教示いただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

### 追記

ご教示いただいた方法で実装したところ、望む動作になりました。
ありがとうございます。

前)

```
void dwgopen()
{
    ...
    ads_command(RTSTR,_T(".OPEN"),RTSTR,filePath,RTNONE);

    //元々開いていた図面を閉じる処理
    ...
}
```

後)

```
void openDocHelper( void *pData)
{
    AcApDocument* pDoc = acDocManager->curDocument();
    if (acDocManager->isApplicationContext()) {
        acDocManager->appContextOpenDocument((const GCHAR *)pData);
    } else {
        acutPrintf( _T("\nドキュメント作成に失敗: %s"),(const char *)pData );
    }

    //元々開いていた図面を閉じる処理
    ...
}

void dwgopen()
{
    ...
    acDocManager->executeInApplicationContext(openDocHelper, (void *)filepath);
}
```

また、補足ですが、本処理後に別のコマンドにてダイアログの表示時にエラーが発生するようになり、表示前に「CAcModuleResourceOverride resourceOverride;」を追加することで解決しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ads_command関数ではOPENコマンドを呼び出すことは出来ません。

図面を開くのであれば、GcApDocManager::SendStringToExcute関数でOPENコマンドを呼び出すか、
GcApDocManager::appContextOpenDocument関数を使用して図面を開いてみてください。

また、appContextOpenDocument関数はアプリケーションコンテキストで呼び出す必要があります。